Torque free symmetric top directly from Lagrangian and Euler angles
I am trying to find constants of motions of the free symmetric top using the Lagrangian and Euler angles. Although I am familiar with other approaches, I hoped to reach the same result just by starting from the Lagrangian.
$$
L=(I_1+\mu l^2)\left(sin^2(\theta) \frac{d\phi}{dt}^2+ \frac{d\theta}{dt}^2\right)+I_3 \left(cos(\theta) \frac{d\phi}{dt}+ \frac{d\psi}{dt}\right)^2
$$
Here, I am following Landau’s notation.
There are two cyclic coordinates, so I have reached the conclusion that angular momentum components M$_3$ and M$_z$ are constants of motion. Energy is conserved as well because L doesn’t have explicit dependence on time. From the conservation of Energy, I have been able to show that the magnitude of angular momentum $|M|$ is constant as well.
But I couldn’t derive that the angular momentum vector is constant in magnitude and direction. I couldn’t derive that $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=zero$.
I have an expression for $\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ that is the same as the heavy symmetric top (Landau Mechanics 3rd), but I couldn’t reduce it to $|M|/I_1$ as we get just by starting from conservation of angular momentum directly.
I know I should start from the conservation of angular momentum directly since there are no external torques acting on the system, but it bothers me that I cannot derive all these results directly from the Lagrangian.
I thought maybe I should impose some constraints, like the point of contact being fixed and not sliding. But all the constraints that I can think of are shared between the free and heavy symmetric top, so I don’t think they will lead to proving that the angular momentum vector is constant and in and that $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=0$.
So, can you pin what I am missing here? Is it possible that some conserved quantities cannot be seen directly by examining cyclic coordinates and explicit dependence on time? For example, the Laplace–Runge–Lenz vector in the Kepler problem is conserved, but it doesn't look like it falls directly from writing down the Lagrangian.

